# Relationship between rolling over DNSSEC ZSK and validity of RRSIG

Tags: networking, dns

I'm trying to learn more about DNSSEC, and I'm confused about the relationship between the validity period of RRSIG and the lifetime of ZSK.

When a RRSIG expires, does that mean it needs to be signed with a new ZSK? I've seen examples of RRSIG with validity periods as short as 2 days. Does that mean the ZSK is rollover every 2 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a RRSIG expires, does that mean it needs to be signed with a new ZSK?

No, you sign the records again with the same ZSK. It's the **signature** that expires, not the key.

Comment: So if the RRset is the same, and the ZSK is the same, you get the same signature?

Comment: No, because the signature also covers the (updated) timestamps, not only the raw RRset. (If it did not, an attacker could just forward-date an old signature.) By re-signing you keep extending the validity range.